# ARM Assembly: Array Address not loading properly?

Tags: arrays, assembly, arm, memory-address

I am working on this homework assignment, and my professor is stumped (as I am too) on why my array address refuses to load into R2. He said my code is correct, but he is absolutely uncertain about why it is behaving this way. It used to load 10 constantly, however, under the branch `manageArray:`, it **should** be overwriting the old use of R2. I even tried re-initializing the value, and it never worked.

We have run it under ARMSim, and code it as a .s file under notepad++. If anyone can point out what the potential cause is and why (because I ***absolutely*** want to learn from this, not look for answers!), I would be forever in your debt!! We have sat for nearly an hour and sent back so many emails over this, we're just frustrated and lost on where to go. **It always loads a value of 10 or 11, but never the array address.**

This is my code as of now. Basically, it's meant to check for odds (and terminate if true), else, add all of the array and print that total out. Semi-colons (;) are comments in assembly, which is weird.

```
.data
    oddPrompt:          .asciz "This Array is odd: we are terminating this thing.\n\r"
    .align
    terminatedPrompt:   .asciz "YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED!\n\r"
    .align
    totalPrompt:        .asciz "Total : \n\r"
    .align

    arrayLength = 10
    ;determineArrayOdds = arrayLength
    array: .skip arrayLength*4

.text
    mov r0,#0
    mov r1,#0
    mov r2,#arrayLength
    mov r3,#0
    mov r6,#0   ;element 1
    mov r7,#0   ;element 2
    mov r8,#0   ;added values from R7 and R6
    mov r9,#0   ;grandTotal

verifyOdds:
    sub r2, r2, #2
        cmp r2,#2
        blt errorForOdd
        bgt verifyOdds
        beq manageArray

errorForOdd:
;It's odd, so we skip calculating, because we never hit 2
    mov r0,#1
    ldr r1,=oddPrompt
    swi 0x69
    swi 0x11

manageArray:
    ldr r2,=array

loop:
;Here, populate and add array elements.
;R2 will be re-purposed for this to conserve space.
    swi 0x6d
    and r0,r0,#0xff ;get time tick UP to 255 (via hex)
    mov r1,r0
    mov r0,#1
    ;swi 0x6b
        str r1,[r2],#4
        cmp r4,#arrayLength
            addlt r4,r4,#1
            blt loop    ;ORIGINAL 49, now 50
            moveq r4,#0
            ldreq r2,=array
            beq addArray

addArray:
    ldrlt r6,[r2,#0]            ;element 1
    ldrlt r7,[r2,#4]            ;element 2
    add r2,r2,#8
    add r8,r7,r6                ;store to r8
    ;mov r9,r8
    add r9,r8,r9
        cmp r4,#arrayLength
        addlt r4,r4,#1
        blt addArray
        beq total

total:
    mov r0,#1
    ldr r1,=totalPrompt
    swi 0x69
    mov r1,r9   ;r1 has to hold the total to print
    mov r0,#1   ;r0 must be set to true
    swi 0x6b    ;PRINT TOTAL NOW
    swi 0x11            

terminate:
    mov r0,#1
    ldr r1,=terminatedPrompt
    swi 0x69
    swi 0x11
```

Comment: The `ldr r2,=array` is a pseudoinstruction, most likely it gets resolved into a load from a literal pool. You should check disassembly and the value in the literal pool. Maybe it gets overwritten.

Comment: Jester, I have no idea what that means... we've used ldr r2,=array before without issues. What is a psuedoinstruction and disassembly?

Comment: Pseudoinstruction is something that looks like it's an instruction but isn't :) The assembler will replace that with actual instructions. The disassembly is getting back an assembly source from a compiled binary, which will show you what the assembler really produced.

Comment: Thank you Jester! Is there a good source to refer to in order to implement this?